# Outlook COM Add-in: Application_NewMail not getting fired

Tags: vb.net, vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

All

In my outlook 3 different mail ID i have configured.i have given button on command Bar so that by clicking on button it open the forms with 3 mail iD name along with radio button.
Whatever radio button i have selected that inbox mail i need to convert in PDF and stored in physical location....it is working for single mail ID but not working for multiple.

Note:- outlook 2010(Application_NewMail) firing in every mail ID but when i try to office 2007 it is not firing that event.

plz help me....

Answer (score 0):

Here is what MSDN states for the *NewMail* event of the *Application* class:

> The NewMail event fires when new messages arrive in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. If you want to process items that arrive in the Inbox, consider using the ItemAdd event on the collection of items in the Inbox. The ItemAdd event passes a reference to each item that is added to a folder.
>
> The NewMail event does not fire when the user is in offline mode.

You can handle the *NewMailEx* instead.

The [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/) series of articles describe all possible ways for handling new mail events.

Comment: Item_Add event does not work well with large number of items,Anything above the 16 items and the event will not be raised.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The most reliable way to use a timer for checking new emails. Please read the series of articles to the end (all of them).